# What is the PineScript equivalent of MQL4's _Point?

Tags: mql4, pine-script, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4

I am trying to convert this [indicator](https://www.bullforyou.com/Sourcecode/Indicators/153735993217064.html) to PineScript. Couldn't figure out how to get `Point` variable. Is there any way to achieve the same thing in PineScript?

`_Point` official definition:
The `_Point` variable contains the point size of the current symbol in the quote currency.

https://docs.mql4.com/predefined/_point

Updated: Added the indicator code

```
//|                                           Ticks Volume Indicator |
//|                                         Copyright В© William Blau |
//|                                    Coded/Verified by Profitrader |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright В© 2006, Profitrader."
#property link      "profitrader@inbox.ru"
//-----
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 1
#property indicator_color1 Blue
//---- input parameters
extern int r=12;
extern int s=12;
extern int u=5;
//---- buffers
double TVI[];
double UpTicks[];
double DownTicks[];
double EMA_UpTicks[];
double EMA_DownTicks[];
double DEMA_UpTicks[];
double DEMA_DownTicks[];
double TVI_calculate[];

double MyPoint;
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init() {
   IndicatorShortName("TVI("+r+","+s+","+u+")");
   IndicatorBuffers(8);
   SetIndexBuffer(0,TVI);
   SetIndexBuffer(1,UpTicks);
   SetIndexBuffer(2,DownTicks);
   SetIndexBuffer(3,EMA_UpTicks);
   SetIndexBuffer(4,EMA_DownTicks);
   SetIndexBuffer(5,DEMA_UpTicks);
   SetIndexBuffer(6,DEMA_DownTicks);
   SetIndexBuffer(7,TVI_calculate);
   SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE);
   SetIndexLabel(0,"TVI");

    if (Digits == 5 || (Digits == 3 && StringFind(Symbol(), "JPY") != -1))
     MyPoint = Point*10;
    else if (Digits == 6 || (Digits == 4 && StringFind(Symbol(), "JPY") != -1))
     MyPoint = Point*100;
    else
      MyPoint = Point;

   return(0);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator deinitialization function                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()  {
   return(0);
}

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Ticks Volume Indicator                                           |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start() {
   int i,counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
   //---- check for possible errors
   if(counted_bars<0) return(-1);
   //---- last counted bar will be recounted
   if(counted_bars>0) counted_bars--;
   int limit=Bars-counted_bars;
   
   //----
   for(i=0; i=0; i--) {
      EMA_UpTicks[i]=iMAOnArray(UpTicks,0,r,0,MODE_EMA,i);
      EMA_DownTicks[i]=iMAOnArray(DownTicks,0,r,0,MODE_EMA,i);
   }
   for(i=limit-1; i>=0; i--) {
      DEMA_UpTicks[i]=iMAOnArray(EMA_UpTicks,0,s,0,MODE_EMA,i);
      DEMA_DownTicks[i]=iMAOnArray(EMA_DownTicks,0,s,0,MODE_EMA,i);
   }
   for(i=0; i=0; i--) {
     if (iClose(NULL,0,i)==0)
       TVI[i]=EMPTY_VALUE;
     else
       TVI[i]=iMAOnArray(TVI_calculate,0,u,0,MODE_EMA,i);
   } 
   //----
   return(0);
}
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the usage of that variable with the output (a screenshot) to see what it does? I don't quite get the definition.

Comment: Most likely you are looking for  `syminfo.pointvalue` https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v4/#var_syminfo{dot}pointvalue

Comment: @BarisYakut sorry I don't have any example. A good explanation here: https://www.forexfactory.com/showthread.php?t=24165

Comment: @Michel_T. the `syminfo.pointvalue` is always 1 across trading pair. According to the explanation in forexfactory above, it might be `syminfo.mintick`.

Comment: `mintick` - is minimal movement of the price (or a `pip` if it's about forex), whereas `pointvalue` is how much costs one point in chart in currency of the security (e.g, USD). To see where it isn't 1.0 - look at futures (for example, `CL1!`). According to the description you've provided - mql4's `Point` is more like pine's `pointvalue`.